# this.state.items.map is not a function. What might be the solution?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a simple react code that shows the list of API data.
However, it returns me an error "Uncaught TypeError: this.state.items.map is not a function" at line 27.
Could you be able to tell me the reason? I just changed the api key and website name just for security reason.
Please help!

```
import React from "react";

import Form from "./components/Form.js";


const API_KEY = "123123";
class App extends React.Component {
  //initialize state
  state = {
    items: []
  };

  getWeather = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const city = e.target.elements.city.value;
    const state = e.target.elements.state.value;
    const api_call = await fetch(`https://test.com/api/events? 
    locationIds=${city},${state}&client=${API_KEY}`);
    const data = await api_call.json();
    console.log(data);
    //set the values of the state
    this.setState({
      items: data
    });
  }

  render() {
    const itemList = this.state.items.map(
      (item, index) => 
      <li 
        key={index}>
        {item}
      </li>
    )
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello!</p>
        <h1>hi</h1>
        <Form getWeather={this.getWeather}/>
      <ul>
        {itemList}
      </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;

{data: Array(132), success: true}
data: Array(132)
[0 … 99]
0: {id: 110503, link: ""…}
1: {id: 106100, link: ""..}
2: {id: 109675, link: ""..}
```

Comment: before **this.state.items.map**, try log **this.state.items**, check it's array

Comment: when i tried console.log(this.state.items), it returns me the object data. However, I do not see any text(li tag) from my view. What might be the error?

Comment: Should it be like {item.link} so i can get the list of all links?

Comment: If it's an object, it doesn't have **.map** function, you should find the correct data who is an array. can you paste **this.state.items** data in your question?

Comment: It is under the export default app; The object looks like that after writing console.log(this.state.items)

Comment: data.data totally worked. but the problem is i was checking the wrong data

Comment: the code should be this.state.items.data.length > 0 this worked but mine was this.state.items.length > 0 which there wasn't no value in the items lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking for state.items first like such:

```
if(this.state.items){
  const itemList = this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
    <li key={index}> {item} </li>
  )
}
```

Comment: I added a code to chect if the this.state.tiems exist and it returns me the object data as I wrote in the last of my code. However, I do not see any text from the view. What do you think it is the problem?

Comment: data.data totally worked. but the problem is i was checking the wrong data

Answer (score 0):

getWeather api is asynchronous which means render function get called before data is loaded, hence you need a check before you run a map function

```
const itemList = (this.state.items && this.state.items.length > 0) ?
this.state.items.map(
    (item, index) =>
    <
    li key = {
        index
    } > {
        item
    } <
    /li>
) : ''
```

Comment: I added a code to chect if the this.state.tiems exist and it returns me the object data as I wrote in the last of my code. However, I do not see any text from the view. What do you think it is the problem?

Comment: try this `this.setState({
      items: data.data
    });`

Comment: data.data totally worked. but the problem is i was checking the wrong data